# Redirecting key events of child widgets to their parent frame widget

Tags: wxpython

Is there someway of redirecting the key events of all child widgets to the key events of their parent frame in wxpython so that all the key events can be caught in a single method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your child classes just need to post the event with your parent widget as a target using `wx.PostEvent`.  Then your parent widget can bind the event to its event handler.  If you need to know which widget the event came from, you can call `GetName()` on the event.  Here is a small example.

```
import wx

class ChildWidget(wx.TextCtrl):

    def __init__(self, parent, name, pos):
        super(ChildWidget, self).__init__(parent, name=name, pos=pos)
        self.parent = parent
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.keyPressed)

    def keyPressed(self, event):
        wx.PostEvent(self.parent, event)

class MainWidget(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(parent, title=title)

        self.child1 = ChildWidget(self, name="Child1", pos=(0,0))      
        self.child2 = ChildWidget(self, name="Child2", pos=(100,0))

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_KEY_DOWN, self.ChildKeyPressed)

        self.Layout()

    def ChildKeyPressed(self, event):
        print "Keypress from " + event.GetEventObject().GetName()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(redirect=False)
    frame = MainWidget(None, "test")
    frame.Show(True)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just wanted to know if there is some way in which I can do the same thing in which I don`t have to postevent from every child widget I create? Like, just defining it once in the parent frame (or somewhere else) and now no matter how many child widgets I add, I will still get the keydown event in the parent widget?

Comment: Unless something has changed, I don't think there is.  Command events will propagate to parent widgets automatically, but a key event is not one of those.  See the discussion at http://groups.google.com/group/wxpython-users/browse_thread/thread/b63a9893ad8bbc3d/4dc2c2eed8a2ca4f?lnk=gst&q=Key+event+propagation+changed+in+2.8#4dc2c2eed8a2ca4f